# When the notification bar is expanded or collapsed by user neither of activity lifecycle methods gets called

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-lifecycle

When the notification bar is expanded or collapsed by user  neither of activity life cycle methods gets called. Could any one tell me,

- **which life cycle method will be invoked** when notification bar is just expanded by user?
- How can we **detect notification bar expanded by user or not** through program?

Thanks in advance.